# How to interchange the position of Item of a List View manually in android.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have read "n" number of examples even the GITHUB one Please provide me with more relevant code. #getFirstVisibilityPosition(), #setSelection() I have read all these commands but not able to apply them in the order they should be as I m new in this field.

I have got this from some source, other being #DEVBYTES which is using Animation for the swapping.

public void onListItemClick(AdapterView at, View view, int position, long id) {

```
int tmp = sp.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                       sp.set(0, sp.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                       sp.set(position,tmp);
                       at.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please Help!

Comment: do you want to change only two items or want to change all item's position in list view .

Comment: The example I have got and posted is using drag and drop for image but I want it on lists - items 
& yes all the Items.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best possible source code. I have found for the question.

https://sites.google.com/site/ericbharlow/sample-code/DragNDrop.zip?attredirects=0&d=1